# Displaying the text when the button is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
class Poem{
  constructor(title, author, text){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.text = text;
  }
}

class UI{
  static displayPoems(){
    const StoredPoems = [
      {
        title: "placeholder title",
        author: "placeholder author",
        text: "placeholder text"
      },
      {
        title: "placeholder title",
        author: "placeholder author",
        text: "placeholder text"
      }
    ];
    const poems = StoredPoems;

    poems.forEach((poem) => UI.addPoemToTheList(poem));
  }

  static addPoemToTheList(poem){
    const list = document.getElementById('poem-list');
    console.log(list);
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
      <td>${poem.title}</td>
      <td>${poem.author}</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="read">Read</a></td>
    `;
  }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.displayPoems);
```

Hello, I was making a javascript script that would create a table of poems and let the users read the poem when the "read" button is clicked. I coded the first part so the script creates the table. But I couldn't do the part where the user would click the button, created a div and displayed the text. Could I get an helping hand?

Answer (score 1):

If the div is already created and hidden you can use code to show the div.

Example JavaScript:

```js
//function to show div
function showDiv() {
    var div = document.getElementById("DivtoShow");
    //show div
    div.style.display = "block";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you've got the button the user is to click to create the div and display the text. So all you'd need to do then is add a listener to it that calls a function that builds a div, assigns it the text of the poem, and appends it to an existing div (wherever you want it on your page). These MDN pages should help (in order):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Alternately, you could create the div with the text in it in the html file, and assign it the `hidden` tag, then assign a listener to the button that calls a function which uses `.toggleAttribute` to remove/add that tag from the element on button-click.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute

Comment: It is not recommended to introduce links. You should summarise the links in your answer (what they show).